# chrome.downloads.drag() crashes chrome in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a chrome extension with React. The functionality I'm having trouble with right now is allowing users to drag a file that the extension has downloaded into another area in the window.

The file downloads fine, and I have the correct reference to its ID, but when I call `chrome.downloads.drag` with the ID it causes Chrome to crash.

Here is how I have it set up currently:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("drag_image").ondragstart = function() {
      const { downloadId } = this.props;
      chrome.downloads.drag(downloadId);
    }.bind(this);
  }
```

I have also tried adding it as the `onDragStart` function of the item being dragged, adding an event listener to the `window` for `ondragstart` and the problem remains.

My best guess is that chrome is trying to resolve both the API event, and the React drag event simultaneously and getting confused. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are crashing Chrome you should report this at https://crbug.com/